# Being redirected to login page after being already logged in

Tags: php, authentication, redirect, laravel

I have a login form and I'm logging myself in with correct credentials. When you are logged in I did a Redirect to my "about" page (used about page to test this functionality).
I did the above with the following snippet

```
        $input = Input::all();
        $login = Auth::attempt([
            'username' => $input['username'],
            'password' => $input['password']
        ]);

        if($login){
            return Redirect::to('about');
        }
        else{
            dd('not logged in!');
        }
```

This snippet is working perfectly
But now in my route to the about page I add `->before('auth');` So if I'm not logged in that I'm going to be redirected to the login page and if I'm already logged in to continue.

Code snippet:

```
Route::get('about', function(){
    $title = 'About';
    return View::make('about')->with('title', $title);
})->before('auth');
```

But by adding `->before('auth');`, I'm always being redirected to the logging page even after logging in with the correct credentials. So I log in and normally I expect to be redirect to the about page but instead I'm being redirect to the login page again.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Did some more debugging and this is what I've found out:

redirect to my about route and executing this:

```
Route::get('about', function()
{
    dd( Auth::check() ); // This returns false
});
```

But instead of redirecting to my route I'm tried:

```
if($login){
    dd( Auth::check() ); // This returns true
}
```

So after redirecting it seems I'm getting logged out or something like that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have an `Auth` filter and need to check whether logged `in/out`, like :

```
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest()) return Redirect::to('login');
});
```

And this (filter) code should be added in `app/filters.php` and your route (what you have)

```
Route::get('about', function(){
    $title = 'About';
    return View::make('about')->with('title', $title);
})->before('auth');
```

Also, you can use it as given code below

```
Route::get('about', array('before' => 'auth' ,function()
{
    $title = 'About';
    return View::make('about')->with('title', $title);
}));
```

**Update :**

Also, if you are using database for session then make sure that `primary key` is `id` in the model (User Model) and if not then set it manually, like

```
protected $primaryKey = "IdOfTheCustomIDFieldInTheTable";
```

Comment: Yes that is default like that in `app/filter.php` I have the code you said. But I'm still experiencing that problem

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried passing the remember parameter to Auth::attempt?

```
$login = Auth::attempt([
    'username' => $input['username'],
    'password' => $input['password']
], true);
```

Also, which session storage mechanism are you using?

Comment: Yes I just tried it and still the same result. I didn't change anything to the sessions file to be honest, Just went and took a look and it is `native`

Comment: Strange. Is the cookie set (you should be able to check in your browser). I've not experienced any issues at all with Laravel's Auth component.

Comment: I think so because I have a cookie of localhost called `laravel_session`